# Removed string values from geo cordinates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataset, latitude-longitude

I have massive dataset with more than two billion rows and 16 columns.

Two of the columns are latitude and longitude and one column of DateTime.

As the data is raw I am trying to sanitize it. In the process I came across some latitude longitude rows containing datetime which is been taken as `string` and latitude and longitude are `float`.

I am using `re` for other preprocessing but here I am not able to do it.

I want to remove the entire  row which has anything else but latitude and longitude in those two columns.

I am looking for some simple solution in python and pandas which will only remove those rows and keep the rest of the dataset as it is.

**Edit:** The input mini version is shared [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7p8otdk6tjrk9kl/twt_mini_stack.csv?dl=0). Last two columns are `latitude & Longitude` and a column before that is `datetime` row 10 as the error I mentioned.

Appriciate the help..  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is difference if all values are `strings`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[10,20,'d'], 'lon':[4,'hh', 7]}).astype(str)

mask = pd.to_numeric(df['lat'], errors='coerce').notnull() & 
       pd.to_numeric(df['lon'], errors='coerce').notnull()

df = df[mask]
print (df)
  lat lon
0  10   4
```

Or values are mixed - some are numeric and some are strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[10,20,'d'], 'lon':[4,'hh', 7]})

mask = (df['lat'].apply(type) != str) & (df['lon'].apply(type) != str)

df = df[mask]
print (df)
  lat lon
0  10   4
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.read_csv('twt_mini_stack.csv')
#print (df)

mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Lat'], errors='coerce').notnull() &  \
       pd.to_numeric(df['Long'], errors='coerce').notnull()

df = df[mask]
print (df[['Tweeted Datetime','Lat','Long']])
        Tweeted Datetime       Lat      Long
0   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
1   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
2   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
3   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
4   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
5   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
6   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
7   3:59 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
9   3:58 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
10  3:58 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
11  3:58 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
12  3:58 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
13  3:58 PM - 1 Jan 2016  35.68501  139.7514
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer,  latitude and longitude i have given them as float,  while i am peocessing them where there are datetime in between i am getting error ' cannot convert string to float '

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question? You can use my dataframe and change it.

Comment: The dataframe too big and the row with error content is some where in 4 million row counts

Comment: No problem, I need only 10 rows with problematic data (only 3 columns are necessary), for better understanding your problem.

Comment: Or is there any 'awk' command Type for windows where i can remove all the rows which are more or less than 16 columns?

Comment: Unfortunately never use it, I have no idea :(.

Comment: please check the edit section in the question with link to sample input

Comment: It seems it is more problematic. I try `df = pd.read_csv('twt_mini_stack.csv')` and in row `8` are data shifted, there is no `Long` value ad datetime is in `lat` column. So is necesary correct data in this row and Long here is `NaN` ?

Comment: So you need process only last 3 columns and another data are unnecessary? Is some way get shifted data Long like in row 8 or are lost?

Comment: There is shift of data.. But If i keep checking for 'nan' Then there is going to be more than 50% data in error section.  Hence trying to solve this One problem.  For other column manipulation I did not get the error,  i skiped error rows but in this case i am not able to skip.

Comment: I need all the columns in dataset but need to remove the rows where latitude and longitude is not there or any other data is present ..  That's It..

Comment: Ok, then my solution works, all there is some another problem?

Comment: That is It..  Just need to write back all the columns along with the updated Ones

Comment: Hmmm, I am a bit confused. So need remove all rows where are bad `Lat` and `Long` ? (e.g. shifted data where in `Lat` column are `datetimes` (strings), all `NaN`s in `Lat` and `Long` columns and all another non numeric data.)

Comment: In simple words,  read all the columns and from them which ever row of latitude longitude are error remove entire row belonging to all columns

Comment: The code works like a charm ! Thanks again but when I am trying to write all the columns back to `output.csv` I am getting ecdoing error I did include `encoding='utf-8'` in `read_csv()` and still the error is there  `return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 109-111: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: You can try add parameter `encoding = 'utf-8'` to `to_csv`

Comment: Yes I did that as well `encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines = False, low_memory=False` in read and also in write. The error came but the output was generated in mini version. when checked on the original data with 1.6GB in size, It kills the Python right away.